# Rattling sound and loss of power

Tags: toyota, power, rattle

My brother's '85 Toyota Camry with ~190k miles started making a funny rattling sound and lost about a quarter of its power.  The rattling seems to come into play when it's under load, like when he's going up a hill or trying to accelerate strongly. It sounds like it's coming from the transmission.

It sounds like it could be a bearing but that wouldn't explain the power loss.

What kinds of problems could cause these symptoms?

Comment: rattling sound is typically an indicator of [engine pinging or knocking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engine_knocking).

Comment: @amphibient He said it's not pinging or knocking; the engine seems to be running fine.

Comment: Tap on the catalytic converter with a soft rubber mallet and listen for the rattling.

Comment: @Paulster2 he said it's not coming from the exhaust.

Comment: @glenviewjeff - Not the reason I'm suggesting tapping on the converter ... if the cat is plugged due to shattering of the honeycomb, the cat will be plugging the exhaust flow and robbing it of power. That's why I put it down as a comment and not as an answer ... just trying to help eliminate things.

Comment: @glenviewjeff - No need to be sorry and no worries. It's all about helping each other out. You just didn't understand my reasoning and I didn't spell it out. *That* comes down on me. Hopefully we can figure things out :D

Comment: Can you answer year/model/engine/tranny/mileage for this vehicle?

Comment: @Paulster2 he said it's an 85 Camry automatic 190k

Comment: Is there any more information you can provide?  Very difficult question to answer with such limited information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My brother said that it ended up being the timing belt; he assumes it was [broken teeth](https://www.gatestechzone.com/en/problem-diagnosis/synchronous-drive-system).  He didn't really care why because he only needed it fixed enough to pass a "cash for clunkers" program.

Comment: What part of the timing belt caused those symptoms? Was there too much slack and jump timing?

Comment: @yorTsenoJ i'm guessing the tensioner failed allowing the belt to slip. if there's any slack in the belt it hits against the front cover and makes a rattling sound.

Comment: I'll ask him if he knew specifically. He tried working on it himself but couldn't proceed because of an awful stuck bolt, and brought it to a pro.

Comment: @yorTsenoJ See my updated answer, though not much more helpful.  :)